# reformat numbers using regex

Tags: regex, bash, perl

I have a file that contains any of the following number format

```
12.456.7890
12-456-7890    
123.456.7890
(123)456.7890
(123).456.7890
123-456-7890
(123)-456-7890
(123)456-7890
```

Is it possible to use regex substitution so that the final output number will always be on a format (123)456-7890 or (12)456-7890

Comment: Modified the question to include the formats where the 1st part of the number is only 2 digits.

Comment: Yes, it is possible! ;-P

Comment: Modified the solution from Jose to solve my question the regex used is s/\(?(\d+)\)?[-.]?(\d\d\d)[-.]?(\d\d\d)/($1)$2-$3/g;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is:

```
s/\(?(\d\d\d)\)?[-.]?(\d\d\d)[-.]?(\d\d\d\d)/($1)$2-$3/g
```

I should mention that the above will also parse the following two:

```
123)456.7890
(123456.7890
```

Comment: @Dren - Yeah but will the format always work to your solution.

Comment: @sln Pardon my test showed a loop hole on the solution. it would not work if there is a missing digit on the 1st part. for example: 23.456.7890 but it works if it is 123.456.789

Comment: @ikegami modified the question to include the patterns mentioned

Comment: @Jose i was able to modify your solution to capture missing digits on the 1st part of the pattern. I made it to look like this s/\(?(\d+)\)?[-.]?(\d\d\d)[-.]?(\d\d\d)/($1)$2-$3/g;

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using two substitutions:

```
perl -lpe 's/\D//g; s/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/($1)$2-$3/' file
```

The first one removes all characters that aren't numeric. The second one inserts the desired characters between each group.

You should take into account that this approach will make a mess of any lines that aren't like the ones in your sample input. One means of protecting yourself could be something like this:

```
if ((@a = /\d/g ) == 10) { /* perform substitutions */ }
```

i.e. ensure that the number of matches on the line is 10 before proceeding.